# get subtotal value in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, subtotal

I am implementing a shipping method for my store. My method is based on the subtotal value so I need to get subtotal value in my module. How can I call subtotal value in magento 2.2?
for example I want my shipping price be: subtotal/100

Answer (score 2):

use below code to get subtotal in custom shipping method.

```
<?php namespace Meetanshi\Flatshipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface;

class Flatrate extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        $subtotal = $request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();
//Here use your own conditions.
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't find this method in the debugger, but it works. Thanks :)